# Multiple Nginx rewrites are not working properly

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

This is a rewrite for processing GET requests as subdirectories

```
rewrite ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /__api/$1.php?r=$2 last;
rewrite ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /__api/$1.php?r=$2&o=$3 last;
```

`hello-world/var1_test`
to
`/__api/hello-world.php?r=var1_test`
-> Working properly

`hello-world/var1_test/var2_test`
to
`/__api/hello-world.php?r=var1_test&o=var2_test`
->
 Returns 404
Log shows that this request is actually accessing to hello-world/var1_test/var2_test. In short, rewrites are not working.

But it seems first rewrite is working properly while second rewrite is not working.

Is there anything wrong on the code?

EDIT:switching the line will make the rewrite passage on the first line able to use. but not the second line

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.
It was about the directory misconfiguration which I forgot the start and the end of the URI. by using ^ and $ in the regular expression